# $.fn.each over Function objects

Tags: jquery, each

Why this code returns "true"?

```
var object = {one: 1, two: 2};
$(object).each(function () {
    console.log(this === object); // returns "true"
});
```

And this code returns "false"?

```
var object = function() {};
$(object).each(function () {
    console.log(this === object); // returns "false"
});
```

Shouldn't it return "true" as well?
Thank You.

Comment: Well, in the first case `object` is an actual `object` when it is not in the second case (looks like it's a `function`). Why are you expecting the statement `this === object` to return `true` in that case?

Comment: I don't think so. In the second example "object" is also an instance of the Object class:

      var object = function() {};
      console.log(object instanceof Object);  // returns "true"

Comment: So `functions` are also `Object`? Just learn something :)

Comment: Seems like in the second case `this` points to the `HTMLDocument`: `$(function() {}).each(function() {
 console.log(this);
});`

Comment: That's the case. But I think that it should point to the "object" instance. Maybe is it a jQuery bug?

Comment: `$(x)` is the constructor form, do you mean `$.each(x)` ? `$(func)` and `$(obj)` are quite different things - the former being a ready callback, the latter a factory)

Comment: Congrats on accidentally discovering the shortcut *DOM ready handler* jQuery supplies to shorten code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example creates a *disconnected* jQuery object (i.e. not connected to a DOM element) and iterates over that single element, so `this` is your object.

The second one actually uses the function as a DOM ready event handler!

e.g. `$(function(){});` is actually a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){});` so that `this` is actually `document` which is obviously not your function object.